# Yii2: Setting image id with Html::img

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to set **image IDs** when displaying them in Yii2 by using:

```
Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@folderImages') . $data->screenshot, ['id' => 'image'.$data->id, 'height' => '80px', 'class' => 'pull-right']);
```

but rendered view shows no ID in these image tags. The rest (class and height) are ok but not the id.

(Note that `$data->id` is an unique number)

does the img tag allow setting ids?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just found why this was happening. Seems that inside gridview by using

```
'format' => 'html',
```

it filters id. Just replaced with

```
'format' => 'raw',
```

and it works